# Is PHA a programming language?

Tags: syntax

I recently was asked by an fluids engineer to help solve a programming problem. I couldn't help because I could not work out over the phone, or given the following code snippet, what language was being used. The only information I could get was that it was "PHA," and/or PHA-Pro. I'm not sure if this is the language or an IDE.

There is precious little information about this technology on the web, although [this](http://www.dyadem.com/products/pha-pro/index.htm) appears to refer to it, it is basically just marketing material and not useful for solving the problem.

Does someone know what PHA is exactly? Is it a programming language? Is it an IDE? Whatever it is, it must be proprietary, because it seems to be kept very secret.

Here is the code snippet which was causing problems. Can somebody recognise the syntax?

```
Count( Responsibility - Department="Process" where Status ="Closed")
```

Comment: I really doubt this is actually a programming language...any more context (like snippets of the surrounding conversation) to go on? I did a little digging and found nothing that suggests it's a programming language...

Comment: No sorry I don't have any more context than what I've given, which is very much the problem! I am hoping someone here has some experience with whatever it is so they can point me in the right direction, just in case it turns out to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

PHA is a accronym for Process Hazard Analysis which are a set of systematic assessments of potential hazards in industry. [Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Hazard_Analysis)

Pro-PHA is a software tool to manage these assessments so in conclusion I would say it is not a programming language. That being said it does appear from the code block above that this "tool" has a simple query language built in to it. Unfortunately seems all resources are behind a pay wall so I couldn't delve further.

Comment: I am amazed nobody here has any expertise in this area. Unless someone comes along who has actually used PHA-Pro, this is probably going to be the best answer!

Comment: It might be the wrong site for this question I couldn't find a forum or anything that wasn't behind a pay wall for that product.